# How to solve a 'protected_enter(2)' error in GHDL

Tags: vhdl, simulation, ghdl

I'm trying to implement a VHDL-08 version of our `PoC.Simulation` helper package.

The original package uses shared variables to track the simulation status:

- *pass*: all asserts passed
- *stop*: stop all processes

There are several functions and procedures using that internal state. For example a `tbGenerateClock()` procedure is used to create a Clock signal.

In my VHDL-08 version, I'm using protected types for the shared variable. I implemented several 'Methods' (what is the correct terminus for that?), which are using or modifying the internal state variable.

GHDL compiles all my sources and throws an error at runtime:
`C:\Tools\GHDL\0.33dev\bin\ghdl.exe:internal error: protected_enter(2)`
`C:\Tools\GHDL\0.33dev\bin\ghdl.exe:error: simulation failed`

**Is this a GHDL internal error or am I using protected types in a wrong way?**

I created a (hopefully) minimal example ([download from Gist](https://gist.github.com/Paebbels/b50d07632bf2aa62c5c1)) that has only 2 procedures: `generateClock`, `stopSimulation`.

There are also `tb*` wrapper procedures to ensure a compatible interface to my VHDL-93 implementation.

```
library IEEE;
use     IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

package simulation is
  type tSimStatus is protected
    procedure stopSimulation;
    procedure generateClock(signal Clock : out STD_LOGIC; constant ClockPeriod : TIME; Enable : BOOLEAN := TRUE);
  end protected;
  -- stop all simulation processes
  procedure tbStopSimulation;
  -- Generate clock waveform for simulation
  procedure tbGenerateClock(signal Clock : out STD_LOGIC; constant ClockPeriod : TIME; Enable : BOOLEAN := TRUE);
end;

package body simulation is
  type tSimStatus is protected body
    variable stop : BOOLEAN := FALSE;

    procedure stopSimulation is
    begin
      stop := TRUE;
    end procedure;

    procedure generateClock(signal Clock : out STD_LOGIC; constant ClockPeriod : TIME; Enable : BOOLEAN := TRUE) is
      constant HIGH_TIME  : TIME  := ClockPeriod / 2;
      constant LOW_TIME    : TIME  := ClockPeriod / 2;
    begin
      Clock <= '1';
      while not stop loop
        while Enable and not stop loop
          Clock <= '1';
          wait for HIGH_TIME;
          Clock <= '0';
          wait for LOW_TIME;
        end loop;
        wait until (Enable = TRUE) or (stop = TRUE);
      end loop;
    end procedure;
  end protected body;

  shared variable status : tSimStatus;

  procedure tbStopSimulation is
  begin
    status.stopSimulation;
  end procedure;

  procedure tbGenerateClock(signal Clock : out STD_LOGIC; constant ClockPeriod : TIME; Enable : BOOLEAN := TRUE) is
  begin
    status.generateClock(Clock, ClockPeriod, Enable);
  end procedure;  
end package body;

library IEEE;
use      IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use      work.simulation.all;

entity tb is
end entity;

architecture test of tb is
  constant CLOCK_PERIOD : TIME := 10 ns;

  signal Clock    : STD_LOGIC;
  signal Reset    : STD_LOGIC    := '0';
begin
  -- clock process
  process
  begin
    tbGenerateClock(Clock, CLOCK_PERIOD, TRUE);
  end process;

  -- stimuli process
  process
  begin
    wait until rising_edge(Clock);

    Reset    <= '1';
    wait until rising_edge(Clock);

    Reset    <= '0';
    wait until rising_edge(Clock);

    tbStopSimulation;
    wait;
  end process;
end;
```

**Solution:**

1. move clock generation code into the `tbGenerateClock` procedure
2. add a function to the protected type to get the internal stop-state
3. mark this function as `impure`

Here is the modified simulation package:

```
package simulation is
  type tSimStatus is protected
    procedure stopSimulation;
    impure function getState return BOOLEAN;
  end protected;
  -- stop all simulation processes
  procedure tbStopSimulation;
  -- Generate clock waveform for simulation
  procedure tbGenerateClock(signal Clock : out STD_LOGIC; constant ClockPeriod : TIME; Enable : BOOLEAN := TRUE);
end;

package body simulation is
  type tSimStatus is protected body
    variable stop : BOOLEAN := FALSE;

    procedure stopSimulation is
    begin
      stop := TRUE;
    end procedure;

    impure function getState return BOOLEAN is
    begin
      return stop;
    end function;
  end protected body;

  shared variable status : tSimStatus;

  procedure tbStopSimulation is
  begin
    status.stopSimulation;
  end procedure;

  procedure tbGenerateClock(signal Clock : out STD_LOGIC; constant ClockPeriod : TIME; Enable : BOOLEAN := TRUE) is
    constant HIGH_TIME  : TIME  := ClockPeriod / 2;
    constant LOW_TIME   : TIME  := ClockPeriod / 2;
  begin
    Clock <= '1';
    while not status.getState loop
      while Enable and not status.getState loop
        Clock <= '1';
        wait for HIGH_TIME;
        Clock <= '0';
        wait for LOW_TIME;
      end loop;
      wait until (Enable = TRUE) or (status.getState = TRUE);
    end loop;
  end procedure;  
end package body;
```

Comment: This question is not restricted to ghdl 0.33. It's just default ghdl :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protected types are supported in ghdl-0.31 for command line flag --std=02 (for the -2002 standard revision) and gives the same error.

There's a release candidate for 0.32, you're taking your life in own your hands for a 0.33dev which would represent some revision in the source tree beyond 0.32rc1.

Questions on ghdl internals are more properly addressed to the ghdl-discuss mail list and those capable of addressing them and participating on Stackoverflow don't do Windows.

I used a C shell alias

```
find . -iname \*.ad\[bs\] -exec grep -H !* \{\} \;
```

to find **protected_enter** in the ghdl source tree.

In ghdl's source **grt/grt-processes.adb**, procedure `Ghdl_Protected_Enter1` we see comments `-- Protected object already locked.` and `-- Should be locked by the current process.` associated with the **protected_enter(2)** internal error.

You presumably have two separate processes seeking access to `status`.

These are the clock process and stimuli process (and you could have used labels).

IEEE Std 1076-2002, 12.5 Dynamic elaboration:

> b) Execution of a subprogram call involves the elaboration of the parameter interface list of the corresponding subprogram declaration; this involves the elaboration of each interface declaration to create the corresponding formal parameters. Actual parameters are then associated with formal parameters. **Next, if the subprogram is a method of a protected type (see 3.5.1)** or an implicitly declared file operation (see 3.4.1), **the elaboration blocks (suspends execution while retaining all state), if necessary, until exclusive access to the object denoted by the prefix** of the method or to the file object denoted by the file parameter of the file operation **is secured**. ...

Method `tbGenerateClock` calls procedure `status.generateClock` which never returns unless `Stop` is `TRUE`,  `status` is locked and ``` Stop``TRUE ``` depends on the stimuli process which is blocked.

The way out of this appears to be to add an argument to method tbGenerateClock and procedure generateClock eliminating method
tbStopSimulation and procedure stopSimulation.

You're essentially operating `status.generateClock` as if it were a concurrent procedure call in a place only a sequential procedure call should be applicable. It loops while waiting on either input values or passage of time. The `tbGenerateClock` wrapper around the procedure call `status.generateClock` masks the issue (and there is no prohibition I can find in the standard).

It would seem the ghdl complaint is valid albeit the lack of discernible diagnostic messages is notable.

Further if you look at NOTES in 12.5:

> 2—If two or more processes access the same set of shared variables, livelock or deadlock may occur. That is, it may not be possible to ever grant exclusive access to the shared variable as outlined in item b), above. Implementations are allowed to, but not required to, detect and, if possible, resolve such conditions.

The resolution appears to have been to produce an unfathomable error message in lieu of simply allowing simulation time to reach TIME'HIGH, ending the simulation time after a board load of clock transitions.

Personally I'd imagine ghdl quite clever figuring out that there is a deadlock here.

I know of no documentation that can help you here other than reading the ghdl source noted above or developing a thorough understanding from the standard. (Along the lines of 'for the experienced programmer any errors are immediately obvious').

There is no guarantee that another VHDL implementation will indicate in any form that a deadlock has occurred, it's optional.

The behavior you might expect in that case would be a long simulation and eventually seeing a message to the effect that simulation was stopped by reaching TIME'HIGH, without the `tbStopSimulation` procedure call in the stimuli process ever having completed.

You'd essentially have even less information than you have with ghdl (again, 'for the experienced programmer any errors are immediately obvious').

And now you know **protected_enter** (and **protected_leave**) messages are associated with blocking access to protected methods by more than one process in ghdl. (And I had to find that out the hard way too.)

**With paebbels solution**

Moving the access to `Stop` outside the procedure generating `Clock` by using a protected method to access `Stop`s value allows multiple processes to access shared data provided by the protected type, giving exclusive access to the shared variable `status` only long enough to complete the two methods (`tbStopSimulation` and impure function (method) `getState`).

It allows multiple processes to read or update `Stop` giving each exclusive access only long enough to complete the respective method.

I'd normally use a signal to share information between processes but in this case you still need the equivalent of a protected method to update `Stop` should you have multiple processes in an elaborated design able to stop simulation by stopping the clock.

There is also a potential issue of portability based on concurrency (a simulation cycle `Stop` is both read and updated).

You could have an accuracy of one clock because there's no guarantee of execution or resuming order for processes calling methods.  If paebbels is using a pass/fail mechanism to evaluate the result of testing that won't be a problem, and that's a common solution.

So what testbench `tb` does with the change:

[image: tb testbench with solution png]
*(clickable)*

is exactly what the you'll find in the unlabelled process with the comment

```
-- stimuli process
```

Comment: The original code for VHDL-93 uses just tbGenerateClock(...) and a shared variable stopSimulation to do the job (tested in iSim and ghdl, vSim is on the list for tomorrow). I tried it the same way for VHDL-08 but I can't access 'status.stop' from tbGenerateClock. I also tried to implement a getter function in tSimStatus, which returns stop, but I get an access/scope error. The old code is incompatible, because VHDL-08 requires shared variables to be protected. I'll repost this question on the ghdl mailinglist. I was not sure if im using protected types in the wrong way or if it's a ghdl error.

Comment: You know you can declare signals in packages as well? package_declarative_item, IEEE Std 1076-2008 4.7 package declarations. You're using a protected type in the wrong way - 5.6.1 Protected type definitions ..."A protected type implements instantiatiable regions of sequential statements, each of which are guaranteed exclusive access to shared data. ... ", As long as the `tbGenerateClock` method doesn't complete the `tbStopSimulation` call will remain blocked, it's not just a ghdl error.  All these methods are invoked as sequential procedure calls, they're expected to complete.

Comment: If I add a `getSimulationStop` method to the protected type, which just returns the internal stop variable; I get the following error: `reference to variable "stop" violate pure rule for function "getstopsimulation"`. So your suggestion is to use a global signal instead of a shared variable?

Comment: oOo ... I solved it: the method/function must be declared as `impure` because it's using the internal state of the protected type.

Comment: Maybe you could append the 'fix' to your question.  Knowing how you overcame the problem might be valuable.